# Can I scroll background window without giving it focus in i3wm

Tags: x11, mouse, i3, focus

I have disabled accidental touchpad click to activate background windows. However, when I move two fingers or my palm along the touchpad, this generates wheel events and they activate whichever window the cursor is on. Any tips on how to prevent that?

To be clear, I would like to be able to scroll a window using the touchpad, without bringing it into focus.

I'm using the i3 window manager (iw3m). There is no desktop environment.
I am using X11 via `startx`.

Example:

- Let's say I have two terminals open.
- I am typing in the first terminal, but my mouse is currently over the second terminal.
- I have follow mouse off so the first terminal is still the active terminal.
- I pause in my typing and accidentally scroll the second terminal with my palm on the touchpad.
- Now remember I have touchpad tapping off, but I accidentally *scroll* on the touchpad over the second terminal.
- Now my focus is on the second terminal, I do not want that.

Comment: Ok, focus is managed by the window manager, so this is fundamentally a question about i3.

Comment: looks like a bug here - https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/2049